# SwiftUI Button shortcut acting weird

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm have a MTKView in my Macos SwiftUI App project. I am trying to add a button and a shortcut key to play or pause it. But the shortcut act weird.

Model:

```swift
class Playable: ObservableObject {
    //data to play
    var playData: PlayData

    var mtkView: MTKView

    @Published isPlaying = false {
        didSet { mtkView.isPaused = !isPlaying }
    }

    func toggle() {
        isPlaying.toggle()
    }
}

class SomethingPlayable: Playable {
    //manage data of playable
}

class SomeOtherThingPlayable: Playable {
    //manage data of playable
}
```

SwiftUI View

```swift
Button {
    //play when mtkView is paused, pause when mtkView is playing.
    playable.toggle()
} label: {
    Image(systemName: playable.isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")
}
.keyboardShortcut(.space, modifiers: [])
```

Playable is responsible for storing the data required by MTKView and controlling MTKView. Subclasses of Playable are responsible for managing data. If I click the play button it works as I expected. But the weird thing is that if I use the shortcut, like press the space key, the code act totally different. More specifically, if I use the shortcut to trigger the play button, the playable variable in the action of the play button will be an empty, just initialized, Playable instance, although it should be full of data loaded by an instance of SomethingPlayable or SomeOtherThingPlayable.

If I cast playable into a instance of SomethingPlayable or SomeOtherThingPlayable as below and call toggle(), then the button won't even be triggered when I press the space key.

SwiftUI View

```swift
Button {
    //play when mtkView is paused, pause when mtkView is playing.
    //playable.toggle()
    if let something = playable as? SomethingPlayable {
        something.toggle()
    } else if let someOtherThing = playable as? SomeOtherThingPlayable {
        someOtherThing.toggle()
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: playable.isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")
}
.keyboardShortcut(.space, modifiers: [])
```

I'm very new to Macos application development and trying to get familiar with Swift and SwiftUI. Am I missing something?

xcode version: Version 15.0
swift version: 5
macOS version: Ventura 13.6

Comment: The button and its shortcut are just working fine (tested it). It must be in the cast part ...

Comment: Is the “else” running?

Comment: @ChrisR Yes.  I figured out that the shortcut works fine. When I press the shortcut key the playable will be set to an preset default empty value. That's what trouble me now.

Comment: @loremipsum yes. The shortcut works fine.

Comment: `isPlaying` needs to be `@State` and pass `@Binding` to a `PlayableButton` `View` struct, remove the classes.

Answer (score 0):

.keyboardShortcut works just fine.

When I change the shortcut to something like command+p, the keyboardShortcut works just fine.  But if the shortcut was set to .space with empty modifier, the keyboardShortcut will trigger something that I still can't track. And this is another problem. When I figure it out, I will update this answer.

Thanks.

update:
I tried to trace the update of the view where play button located. Below is what I do.

```swift
struct PlayerCtlView: View {
    @ObservedObject var playable: TSPlayable
    private var uuid = UUID()

    init(playable: TSPlayable) {
        self.playable = playable
        printUUID()
    }

    private func printUUID() {
        print("PlayerCtlView.uuid = \(uuid)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            //play when mtkView is paused, pause when mtkView is playing.
            printUUID()
            playable.toggle()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: playable.isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")
        }
        .keyboardShortcut(.space, modifiers: [])
    }
}
```

I add a uuid property in the view and whenever PlayerCtlView was initialized it will be set a new value and print it.  When play button was triggered print this uuid too. Then, I discovered something interesting. Whenever I press the space shortcut key to trigger the play button, the UUID will be the same one. The one was set when PlayerCtlView was initialized the first time.  And the view will act like it was just initialized the first time. Although the PlayerCtlView has updated serval times and the uuid has changed serval times. And no matter what the uuid was set when the PlayerCtlView was updated the latest time.  If I change the short cut to something else, like command+P, it will work normally.

Apparently, SwiftUI intercepts some keyboard input, like space and tab, and do something quietly before it respond to user input.  Investigating this phenomenon is far beyond my ability. So I'll put this issue aside for now.